# Как сделать так, чтобы при экспорте файла в Obsidian был черный фон?

Tags: pdf, markdown

Хочу экспортировать файл в обсидиане в PDF:

[image: Внешний вид файла]

Но на выходе фон получается белый, что мне не нужно:

[image: Внешний вид PDF]